# Tic tac toe game project, using images instead of letters "X" and "O"

Tags: java

So now, this is tic tac toe game project, and this Computer vs player game. In this game project I am using letters "X" and "O" for cross sign and circle sign. It work's fine, there is no error.

Now I am thinking to use Images instead of letters  X and O.
please give me suggestions how can I use pictures. I am not looking for code, just give me suggestion, what should I need to add or replace.

The code below is the code for tic tac toe

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
    /*Instance Variables*/
    static int[][] winCombinations = new int[][] {
            {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, //horizontal wins
            {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, //vertical wins
            {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}             //diagonal wins
        };
    static JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    static JButton buttons[] = new JButton[10];
    static int count = 0;
    static  String letter;
    static boolean win = false;
    static  String myImage =  "X";
    static  String Image = "O";


    public TicTacToe(){
        /*Create Window*/
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        /*Add Buttons To The Window*/
        for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            window.add(buttons[i]);

            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        /*Make The Window Visible*/
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
    {
        /*Write the letter to the button and deactivate it*/
        for(int i = 1; i<= 9; i++){

            if(a.getSource() == buttons[i]){
                buttons[i].setText(myImage);
                buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        count++;        
        AI();

    }

    public void AI(){
        count++;


         if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText(Image);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText(Image);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText(Image);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } 

        else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText(Image);
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setText(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText(Image);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText(Image);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText(Image);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[8].setText(Image);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText(Image);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[8].setText(Image);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText(Image);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText(Image);
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText(Image);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText(Image);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText(Image);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText(Image);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText(Image);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText(Image);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText(Image);
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText(Image);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText(Image);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText(Image);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText(Image);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage)) {
            buttons[6].setText(Image);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);            
        }    

        else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage)) {
            buttons[4].setText(Image);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);            
        }

        else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText(Image);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText(Image);
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        }
        else {
            if(count >= 9)
                checkWin();
            else
                RandomMove();
        }

        checkWin();

    }

    public void RandomMove(){
        Random x = new Random();
        int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
        if(buttons[y].getText().equals(Image) || buttons[y].getText().equals(myImage)){
            RandomMove();
        } else {
            buttons[y].setText(Image);
            buttons[y].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void checkWin(){ 

        /*Determine who won*/
        for(int i=0; i<=7; i++){
            if( buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][1]].getText()) && 
                buttons[winCombinations[i][1]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][2]].getText()) && 
                !buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals("")) {
                win = true;
            }
        }

        if(count % 2 == 0)
            letter = Image;
        else
            letter = myImage;

        /*Show a dialog when game is over*/
        if(win == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(count >= 9 && win == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game was tie!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```

Comment: `JButton` has a `setIcon` method for setting images

Comment: yes i used setIcon method, After running program, when i clicked on the first button it puts x image on  the button and also computer puts automatically o images in the center, after that when i click on the next button, it puts an image x, but it doesn't show up me the image of "o". it just keep on showing images of x

Comment: You should post that code if you wish to ask a question about that

Comment: Your code is very redundant and would benefit from refactoring. This would not only make it easier to read and maintain, but it would make it much easier for you and us to debug it.

Comment: oke... i will do that...